# What is the difference between std::lower_bound and std::upper_bound?

Tags: c++

The code below does not compile with both MSVC2017 and GCC11:

```
#include <deque>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>

using Clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;

struct PricePoint
{
    TimePoint dt;
    double buy;
    double sell;
};

inline bool operator < (const TimePoint & dt, const PricePoint & a)
{
    return a.dt < dt;
}

int main()
{
    std::deque<PricePoint> priceSequence;
    const auto begin = std::lower_bound(priceSequence.begin(), priceSequence.end(), Clock::now());
    return 0;
}
```

But if I replace `std::lower_bound` with `std::upper_bound` it starts to compile. What is the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> error: no match for 'operator<'

This sort of error suggests that some template code is trying to use an operator you haven't defined.

`lower_bound` and `upper_bound` do opposite comparisons.`< (const TimePoint & dt, const PricePoint & a)` is fine for `upper_bound`, but `lower_bound` needs you to define this:

```
inline bool operator < (const PricePoint & a, const TimePoint & dt)
{
    return dt < a.dt;
}
```